# Errores BadPaddingException y IllegalBlockSizeException al encriptar archivos con AES

Tags: java, encriptación

El siguiente código me lanza el error cuándo selecciono un archivo un poco pesado como un `Word`:

> BadPaddingException

Y este error cuándo selecciono un archivo simple `txt`:

> IllegalBlockSizeException

Estos errores solo me aparecen al **desencriptar**.

GUI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uCwA.jpg

```
byte[]archivo=null;
byte[]archivoEncriptado=null;
SecretKey LLAVESECRETA=null;
final int AES_KEYLENGTH = 128;
IvParameterSpec IV;
public NewJFrame() {
    try{
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    }catch(Exception ex){}
    initComponents();
    generarIVyClave();
}

private byte[] leerBytes1(){
    byte[]archivoBy=null;
    try{
        JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
        int rep=chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(rep==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath(), "r");
            archivoBy=new byte[(int)aFile.length()];
            FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();                
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(archivoBy.length);
            buffer.get(archivoBy);
            buffer.clear();
            String salida="";
            while(inChannel.read(buffer) > 0)
            {
                buffer.flip();
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++)
                {
                    salida+=(buffer.get()+"|");
                    if(i!=0)if(i%10==0)salida+="\n";

                }
                buffer.clear(); // do something with the data and clear/compact it.
            }
            jTextArea1.setText(salida);

            inChannel.close();
            aFile.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}        
    return archivoBy;
}

private byte[] leerBytesDelArchivoCifrado(){
    byte[]archivoBy=null;
    try{
        JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
        int rep=chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(rep==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath(), "r");
            archivoBy=new byte[(int)aFile.length()];
            FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(archivoBy.length);
            buffer.get(archivoBy);
            buffer.clear();
            String salida="";
            while(inChannel.read(buffer) > 0)
            {
                buffer.flip();
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++)
                {
                    salida+=(buffer.get()+"|");
                    if(i!=0)if(i%10==0)salida+="\n";

                }
                buffer.clear(); // do something with the data and clear/compact it.
            }
            jTextArea3.setText(salida);                
            inChannel.close();
            aFile.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}        
    return archivoBy;
}
private void btnMostrarArchivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    this.archivo=leerBytes1();
}                                                 

private void generarIVyClave(){
    try{
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(128);
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
        this.LLAVESECRETA=secretKey;    // change this as desired for the security level you want
        byte[] iv = new byte[this.AES_KEYLENGTH / 8];   // Save the IV bytes or send it in plaintext with the encrypted data so you can decrypt the data later
        SecureRandom prng = new SecureRandom();
        prng.nextBytes(iv);
        this.IV=new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    }catch(Exception ex){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);}
}
private void encriptarAES(byte[]archivo){
    try {

        Cipher aesCipherForEncryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"); // Must specify the mode explicitly as most JCE providers default to ECB mode!!

        aesCipherForEncryption.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.LLAVESECRETA, IV);

        byte[] archivoCifrado = aesCipherForEncryption.doFinal(archivo);
        this.archivoEncriptado=archivoCifrado;

        String salida="";
        for(int i=0;i<archivoCifrado.length;i++){
            salida+=(archivoCifrado[i]+"|");
            if(i!=0)if(i%10==0)salida+="\n";
        }
        jTextArea2.setText(salida);
    }

    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgo) {
            System.out.println(" No Such Algorithm exists " + noSuchAlgo);
    }

    catch (NoSuchPaddingException noSuchPad) {
            System.out.println(" No Such Padding exists " + noSuchPad);
    }

    catch (InvalidKeyException invalidKey) {
            System.out.println(" Invalid Key " + invalidKey);
    }

    catch (BadPaddingException badPadding) {
            System.out.println(" Bad Padding " + badPadding);
    }

    catch (IllegalBlockSizeException illegalBlockSize) {
            System.out.println(" Illegal Block Size " + illegalBlockSize);
    }

    catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException invalidParam) {
            System.out.println(" Invalid Parameter " + invalidParam);
    }

}
private void desencriptarAES(byte[]archivoEncriptado){
    try {
        Cipher aesCipherForDecryption = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"); // Must specify the mode explicitly as most JCE providers default to ECB mode!!

        aesCipherForDecryption.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.LLAVESECRETA, this.IV);

        byte[] archivoDesCifrado = aesCipherForDecryption.doFinal(archivoEncriptado);
        this.archivo=archivoDesCifrado;

        String salida="";
        for(int i=0;i<archivoDesCifrado.length;i++){
            salida+=(archivoDesCifrado[i]+"|");
            if(i!=0)if(i%10==0)salida+="\n";
        }
        jTextArea5.setText(salida);
    }

    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgo) {
            System.out.println(" No Such Algorithm exists " + noSuchAlgo);
    }

    catch (NoSuchPaddingException noSuchPad) {
            System.out.println(" No Such Padding exists " + noSuchPad);
    }

    catch (InvalidKeyException invalidKey) {
            System.out.println(" Invalid Key " + invalidKey);
    }

    catch (BadPaddingException badPadding) {
            System.out.println(" Bad Padding " + badPadding);
    }

    catch (IllegalBlockSizeException illegalBlockSize) {
            System.out.println(" Illegal Block Size " + illegalBlockSize);
    }

    catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException invalidParam) {
            System.out.println(" Invalid Parameter " + invalidParam);
    }

}
private void btnEncriptarArchivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    if(jTextArea1.getText().length()>0){
        encriptarAES(this.archivo);
    }
}                                                   

private void generarArchivoEncriptado(byte []archivoEncriptado){
    try{
        JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
        int rep=chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if(rep==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath(), "rw");
            this.archivoEncriptado=new byte[(int)aFile.length()];
            FileChannel outChannel = aFile.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(archivoEncriptado);
            outChannel.write(buffer);
            outChannel.force(true);
            outChannel.close();
            aFile.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
private void generarArchivoRecuperado(byte []archivo){
    try{
        JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
        int rep=chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if(rep==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath(), "rw");
            archivo=new byte[(int)aFile.length()];
            FileChannel outChannel = aFile.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(archivo);
            outChannel.write(buffer);
            outChannel.force(true);
            outChannel.close();
            aFile.close();
            jTextField1.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile().getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){} 
}
private void btnGenerarArchivoEncriptadoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                            
    generarArchivoEncriptado(this.archivoEncriptado);
}                                                           

private void btnLeerArchivoEncriptadoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                         
    this.archivoEncriptado=leerBytesDelArchivoCifrado();
}                                                        

private void btnRecuperarArchivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    generarArchivoRecuperado(this.archivo);
}                                                   

private void btnDesencriptarArchivoEncriptadoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                                 
    desencriptarAES(this.archivoEncriptado);
}
```

Comment: No he probado el código pero con una leída rápida de la excepción y el código me parece que el problema está en cómo lees los bytes del archivo. Si necesitas tener todos los bytes en memoria, sería mejor utilizar un `ByteArrayOutputStream`

Comment: Antes de usar las librerias `java.nio.*` usaba las de `java.io.*` y la lectura de bytes lo hacia al menos sin demorarse con archivos que no pasan de los 500 bytes, con mas el programa se congelaba por un largo tiempo, en cambio use el .nio y me puede leer hasta 500 kb. Creo que debe quedarse con el `ByteBuffer`

Comment: Eso es problema del algoritmo. Cuando lees los contenidos de un archivo como bytes, debes hacerlo en pequeñas partes (conocidos como chunks), usualmente entre 1k (1024 bytes) y 8k (8196 bytes). Lo que haces aquí es tratar de leer todo el contenido del archivo de un solo golpe, y esa acción es lenta, sin importar si utilizas `java.io` o `java.nio`. Por otro lado, me parece que se pierden bytes en la lectura, por ende las excepciones.

Comment: Ya detecte el problema y todo estaba al momento de leer los bytes, el programa ya encripta y desencripta, y use un `MappedByteBuffer`. Ahora tengo un problema al desencriptar archivos rar o zip, Al abrirlos sale un mensaje de error "No se puede abrir el archivo". Lo mismo no pasa con otros como pdf docx txt pptx exe etc. A que se deberia?